# jQuery Ajax with JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm coming from Prototype.js where I handle all of my ajax calls like:

```
function ajax_request (page, func) {
    new Ajax.Request (page, { method : 'post', parameters : { JSON : func } } );
}

function test_func (data) {
    alert(data);
}

//example
ajax_request('/ajax.php', 'test_func');
```

And the PHP:

```
$data_array = array()
$data_array['test'] = 'test data';    

header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 200 OK", True, 200);
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
echo $_POST['JSON'] . '(' . json_encode($data_array) . '); //';
```

I'm trying to accomplish something similar in jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be working the same way. I'm using the following with jQuery, which makes the request, but the test_func doesn't get called.

```
function ajax_request (page, func) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'JSON=' + func
    });
}
```

It is quite likely I've been doing this the best way from the beginning, so the answer doesn't have to replicate the method used with Prototype.js if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: What is `func`? How is `test_func` called in your first example? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my best interpretation of what you're asking, I'd say that the `parameters`option from Prototype.js is the same thing as the `data` param in jQuery. Although jQuery does allow you to use a URL formatted query string as `data`, I recommend pass an object for it to serialize properly:

```
function ajax_request (page, func) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            JSON: func
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the json object as data parameter to jquery ajax. In order for test_func to get called you have to provide the success handler to ajax method.

```
function ajax_request (page, func) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { JSON : func },
        success: test_func
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for same answer (and you even added an extra bit of valuable info)

Comment: @James - Please dont forget to accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: It turns out setting success isn't required for this to work. Also, there's no need to "remind" me to accept an answer, does it look like I'm new here to you?

Comment: I specified the success handler because you had mentioned its not getting called in your question. [I'm using the following with jQuery, which makes the request, but the test_func doesn't get called.]

Comment: I knew that was the only issue, again I am mentioned you had mentioned something in your question please read   [I'm using the following with jQuery, which makes the request, but the test_func doesn't get called.]